# Gaming Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, design, community

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a gaming.stackexchange moderator, would you be interested in having your own Gaming Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local gaming sessions or meetups.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: gaming.stackexchange.com moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: Would there be any opportunity for non-mods to get these to pass out at stuff like gaming conventions and such?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes - +1. It'd be neat to have a business card to show off.

Comment: @Fallen @Raven for now these are for mods only. However we do [sponsor](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/2052/) users go to go conferences. In which case I think having cards for those people is a good idea, regardless they're mods or not. If you go to a non-sponsored conf(e.g. blizzcon etc) it may be handy to have cards too. I'll talk to the team about this. Basically we should support anything that'd help to promote the site.

Comment: @Jin - remember, only the first @<user> alerts them! (I found the comment on my own, at least this time)

Comment: same advice as before: drop the "passionate" on the back and simplify to "a Q&A site for videogamers".

Comment: This makes me regret not being a mod here :P

Comment: @Jin That reminds me of summat... thanks.

Comment: Man, URLs are so 2008. It's all about the QR codes now! (but regardless, I love the design)

Comment: @Jin - what about a possibility for templates then, so that we could stackexchange style buisness cards on our own dime?

Comment: @Oak has a point, why not add a QR code somewhere? Too much going on?

Comment: Can we vote to close this as too localized?  ;)  (3 moderators vs. the rest of us)

Comment: @Juan @Oak yeah it'd be too much. Also, as much as I like QR as a nice geeky novelty, but in reality no one uses it. (unless you're in Japan).

Answer (score 9):

This would make promoting the site a whole lot easier. Gaming's easy to say. Getting people to remember "Stack Exchange", though, after a round of gaming (which is either going to be incredibly fun filled, or incredibly curse filled), would be a challenge. Card would help a lot.

Count that as a yes from me.

Answer (score 4):

They look awesome.

> Would you be interested in having your own Gaming Stack Exchange contact card?

Yes

> Would you find it useful?

Very

> Anything else?

Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

OK, moderators have officially been mailed the form to obtain the cards. Stay tuned!